# AttributeError: crs attribute is not available

Tags: python, python-3.x, metpy

All,
I am using metpy 0.10.0, I am trying to calculate the laplacina of a field using mpcalc.laplacian function, yet I get the following error :
AttributeError: crs attribute is not available.

Here is my minmal code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xarray as xr
import metpy.calc as mpcalc

myfile   = xr.open_dataset(diri+"vor_geo_era5_2023_jan.nc")
var_z    = myfile['z']   # geopotential m**2 S**-2
   
timeP     = myfile['time']
lonP      = myfile['longitude'].data
latPP     = myfile['latitude'].data
lap       = mpcalc.laplacian(var_z[:,:,:],axes=('latitude','longitude'))
```

I tried to use `var_z.metpy.assign_latitudde_longitude(force=False)` as illustrated here [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76424703/the-laplacian-of-metpy-cant-convert-the-units-of-temperature-advection) , yet I get the following error
AttributeError: 'MetPyAccessor' object has no attribute 'assign_latitudde_longitude'
Thanks

Comment: You have a typo: two `d` in `latitudde`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment above is correct, the error is showing you have a typo, the correct method name is `assign_latitude_longitude()`.

That said, this method was added in MetPy 1.0, so you'll need to upgrade to a more recent version of MetPy in order for this to work.